# can't su to a local account

Tags: ssh, ldap, pam

I am trying following [this guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_OpenStack_Platform/2/html/Getting_Started_Guide/ch02s03.html)to give root privileges to a user called deploy.

But I am unable to su to deploy user.

Steps I have taken,

logged in as a root user then I added the deploy which is a local user

```
su deploy (giving the deploy users password here)
```

I always get su: incorrect password with the correct password.

And I am seeing following on my /var/log/secure

```
su: pam_sss(su:auth): received for user deploy: 10 (User not known to the underlying authentication module)
```

out put of

```
getent passwd deploy 
deploy:x:500:501::/home/deploy:/bin/bash
```

content of my /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
# This file is controlled by Puppet

passwd:     files sss
shadow:     files sss
group:      files sss
hosts:      files dns
bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files
netgroup:   files sss
publickey:  nisplus
automount:  files
aliases:    files nisplus
```

/etc/shadow relevant line

```
deploy:xxxxxxxxxx:17204:0:99999:7:::
```

Comment: Please post your `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

Comment: Can you post the relevant line from `/etc/shadow`? (Don't forget to hide your password hash if it's there)

Comment: https://fedorahosted.org/sssd/wiki/Troubleshooting#TroubleshootingAuthenticationPasswordChangeandAccessControl - you should have meaningful messages in your logs. Where does the account reside? On ldap or files? Did you restargsssd?

Answer (score 0):

In your text, you are implying that you are writing the password for the deploy user in the `su` command line as a second argument after the username.

`su` command doesn't take password as a command line argument. If it needs a password, it will ask it via terminal.

When you are running su as the `root` user, it does not ask passwords for users.